# 3-year UK Tier 2 extension on passport that will expire in a year

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, south-african-citizens

I have a quick question. I hope someone can help. We are currently on a Tier 2 General visa (3 years), which expires in July 2018.

We will be applying for an extension closer to the time. The problem is that my kid's passport is already 3 years old and I am concerned that this will affect the time given on the visa extension, since kids passports are only valid for 5 years. We would ideally want to get another 3 years, which would give us enough time to apply for ILR.

1. Does anyone know if this will affect the application? Should I rather get new passports for the kids.
2. Is there a faster way to get the passports, from a South African company? It looks like the wait time through SA House is 4 months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't your children get biometric residence cards which are separate from passports? My niece got one at age 10 and it was not tied to the expiration date of her passport.

Comment: They do, but when we moved to the UK, we still got the Visa stamps in our passports. We can switch to BRP's but that is about £165 or something. It is not worth the money with the visa's expiring in a few months.

Comment: I would expect that when you renew the visa your children will be given BRPs by default and they will have the same validity period as your own, independent of the expiration date of their passports. Once you have the card you can renew the passports as needed.

Comment: I used to carry my expired US passport with my still valid visa and my new US passport when traveling. Never had a problem. Not sure if SA will give you the expired passport back.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to track down other South Africans that is in the same boat as me. They said, I should be able to get the full 3 year visa, then I can just renew passport. After which I would need to let UK home office know about the Passport nr change. I will post the answer after I have renewed the visa's